# Advanced Filters with Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping to combine two advanced filters and can't seem to get it right.

The goal is to filter down to only the rows with both a FIN from a list and a userID from a list.  Below are the filters individually.

When I run them sequentially, only the last filter is applied.

```
'   Filter by FINs
LastRow2 = Sheets("FINs").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Data").Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets("FINs").Range("A1:A" & LastRow2), Unique:=False
'   Filter by userID
LastRow3 = Sheets("Users").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Data").Columns("C:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets("Users").Range("A1:A" & LastRow3), Unique:=False
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't apply two advanced filters on the same range. You can achieve this, however, with a normal `AutoFilter`, that you can apply on the two fields in sequence. You can also do that with *one* advanced filter, but the two criteria ranges need to be put together in one worksheet near each other. You can eventually copy the two criteria ranges (by code) into a temporary new worksheet for that matter, then remove it after applying the advanced filter.

Comment: I can temporarily copy the values to the same sheet, but I'm not savvy enough with vba to get the advanced filter syntax right.  Can you help me out with what that would look like?

Comment: Is column `B` of `Sheets("FINs")` free of data? If so you can copy into it the other list from `Sheets("Users")`.

Comment: They will be differing lengths, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with AutoFilter, then pass in Array(FIN 1, FIN 2,..) and Array(User 1, User 2,...), but it didn't work exactly.

Eg,

I want list down only having FIN 1 in Col A, then Col B must be User 1
But the result is not, As long as Col A have FIN 1 it will in the list. Auto Filter will return all combination possible across these 2 arrays.

I recommend add a Unique Column, then filter using the Unique column instead.
Then filter using AutoFilter with Array as below:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$7").AutoFilter Field:=3, 
    Criteria1:=Array("FIN 2|User 2", "FIN 4|User 4", "FIN 5|User 5", "FIN 6|User 6"), 
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

[image]